# The evaluation of 'requires expression' without usage of 'concept'

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, c++-concepts

**Update: Jun 11th, 2022

Microsoft had fixed this since about 19.30 (kindly tested by user @Vuwox)**
Link to the MSVC feedback:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-evaluation-of-requires-expression/10059954

I am currently running into an issue that I am unsure whether it is a compiler error or not.
(The following test are running on https://godbolt.org/)
The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

struct A{};
struct B
{
    template<typename... Tys>
    bool IsPlayer() const noexcept
    {
        cout << "B::IsPlayer\nType count: " << sizeof...(Tys) << '\n';
        ((cout << typeid(Tys).name() << '\n'), ...);
        return sizeof...(Tys) > 1;
    }
};
struct C{};

template <typename... Tys>
struct Prefab_t
{
    using Tuple_t = std::tuple<Tys...>;
    Tuple_t m_tuple{};

    bool IsPlayer(void) const noexcept
    {
        auto fnHelper = [&]<typename T>(const T & Component) -> bool
        {
            //if constexpr (std::is_invocable_r_v<bool, decltype(&T::template IsPlayer<Tys...>), T const* const>)
            if constexpr (requires(const T& t) { {t.template IsPlayer<Tys...>()} noexcept -> std::same_as<bool>; })
            {
                cout << "fnHelper<"<<typeid(T).name() << ">\nType count: " << sizeof...(Tys) << '\n';
                ((cout << typeid(Tys).name() << '\n'), ...);
                return Component.template IsPlayer<Tys...>();
            }
            else if constexpr (requires(const T& t) { {t.IsPlayer()} noexcept -> std::same_as<bool>; })
                return Component.IsPlayer();
            else
                return false;
        };

        return (fnHelper(std::get<Tys>(m_tuple)) || ...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Prefab_t<A, B, C> ent;
    cout << boolalpha << ent.IsPlayer();
    return 0;
}
```

With `x86-64 gcc 12.1` and option `-std=c++20`, I got the wanted output:

```
fnHelper<1B>
Type count: 3
1A
1B
1C
B::IsPlayer
Type count: 3
1A
1B
1C
true
```

However, with compiler `x64 msvc v19.latest` and option `/std:c++20`, I got the unexpected output:

```
B::IsPlayer
Type count: 0
false
```

It seems like the lambda function `fnHelper` failed the `if constexpr` test and called the B::IsPlayer without any template argument.
Is my usage of `requires` expression correct? Is this way of use even legit?
Thank you.

PS please don't be harsh on me, I am just a chemical guy who has some interest in C++...

**Edit:**

1. Shame on me, I even spelled "correct" wrongly to "current"...
2. (June/01) Tested on Windows 11 with MSVC 2022 Community 17.3.0 Preview 1.1, exact same error. Triggered the contain of `else if constexpr` line via breakpoint debug.

Comment: Nah, looks like you aren't using it [the right way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), also you should check [compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) to check wether msvc is good enough to use things you wanna use

Comment: [Clang agrees with GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/bceWjx5aq), which is somewhat reassuring . @Sugar - There is nothing "wrong" about an inline requires expression. They are as the name implies, expressions, and can be used anywhere a corresponding `bool` expression may appear.

Comment: clang is pretty much have the same API as GCC, so agreement between them is expected. 
I don't see anything about inline concepts and their usage in the middle of the function in docs I reffered. Maybe there's something in the proposal, didn't actually read. MSVC probably don't support it (yet?) and there's just stab to evaluate it to false or whatever.

Comment: @Sugar - Same API as GCC? Based on what? Sharing flags? They have completely different front *and* back ends, and disagree plenty. They both however, have a better track record in conformance than MSVC, so agreement is *very* indicative. You should also not treat cppreference as a closed and shut source. It's not exhaustive, nor claim to be complete.

Comment: @Hydrogen - Can you try a more recent MSVC? There have been bugs around such usage patterns fixed in the last several months.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it has pretty extensive reference list, including links to proposals and compilers feature state. I specified, that I didn't read actual proposal.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks for your advice! But it appears on the desktop version as well.

Comment: have you tried using c++latest instead of c++20?

Comment: For some time MSVC didn't support `requires` outside of concepts at all. I wouldn't be surprised if the newly added support is borked.

Comment: @Sugar OP is using it fine. Please delete your comments, they're not helpful.

Comment: [Reduced example](https://godbolt.org/z/zese8W6qj), would suggest reporting this to MSVC. This is a clear bug.

Comment: This is working with C++20 (no need c++lastest), for compiler since 19.30. I came to the same problem recently. And just want to emphasis on this: `auto v = requires(const T& t){...}` if you test method that are not `const` it is a issue for MSVC. You can just drop the const inside the requires and it does work for according methods.